# Why not able to start SSH shell though permissions are set?

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, permissions, debian

Due to a recent hack of my servers I am in some kind of ultimate restriction taste and thus wanted to limit the permissions of all the root folders like so:

```
chmod o-x /*
```

To enable login for other users again, I do:

```
chmod o+x /home
```

Now, I have another user which is not root and which should be the only one allowed to login, but it cant - the SSH authentication itself works but then this error appears:

> /bin/sh: Permission denied

Seems easy to grant permissions to the bin folder like so:

```
chmod o+x /bin
```

But I still get the same Permission denied message.

Whats going on here?

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. Try SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: What are the permissions of `/bin/sh`?

Comment: I'll do next time.. thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execute bit (x) on directories allows an user to go into that directory. If you remove the x bit from the root directory (/), then it is not possible to go into that directory and get the details of its contents. But in order to get the details of the bin directory under the / directory, that is necessary.

The same is true for /home and what is in it, by the way.

You might argue that you can do an `ls /` and list it's contents. That is because the contents itself are in the inode of the listed folder. But try to get a detailed listing with `ls -l /` and you will see that the permissions can not be listed. This is because the permissions are in the inode of the bin directory, but without the x permission, you are not allowed to enter the root directory in order to look at that inode.

Removing the x permission bits from the root directory is going to cause lots of problems. Don't do it! Better to learn concepts like SELinux or similar.